# Kill macro returns a 53 error

Tags: excel, vba

This macro returns a 53 error.

If I use the CSVPath2 variable with the Kill command the macro works, but if I use the sProcessFile variable it does not.

```
Sub DELETE()
Dim CSVPath As String
Dim CSVPath2 As String
Dim sProcessFile As String

CSVPath = "c:\TEST\"
'CSVPath2 = "c:\TEST\*.csv"
sProcessFile = Dir(CSVPath & "*.csv")

Kill sProcessFile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the complete filespec *(including the path)*

On my machine:

```
Sub DELETE()
   Dim CSVPath As String
   Dim sProcessFile As String

   CSVPath = "C:\TestFolder\"
   sProcessFile = Dir(CSVPath & "*.csv")
   Kill CSVPath & sProcessFile
End Sub
```